# Why does test of one model insert data to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am totally new to rails, so sorry if this question is stupid. I have a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence:  true,
                    length: {minimum: 5}
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  validates :first_language, presence: true
  validates :second_language, presence: true
end

I wrote the simpliest test for User model:

```
require 'test_helper'
```

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should always pass" do 
    assert true
  end
end

When I run the test I get an error:

```
rake test test/models/user_test.rb 
Run options: --seed 24598
```

## Running:

E

Finished in 0.055609s, 17.9827 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1) Error:
UserTest#test_should_be_valid:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must b
e unique: INSERT INTO "lessons" ("id", "title", "description", "words_qty", "cre
ated_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, 'MyString', 'MyText', 1, '2014-11-12 22:09:52
', '2014-11-12 22:09:52')

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Why does it try to populate Lessons table with this data? And where does this error come from? I checked that Lessons table is empty before tests.

Ok, I figured it out: it was because of duplicated id's in test/fixtures/lessons.yml. Two rows with the same id were added at the beginning of the test to test database and that caused this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Rails project for a file `test/fixtures/lessons.yml` - this defines test data that can be used by your tests. There could be 2 test lessons defined in there with the same ID.